# ошибка при перезапуске сервиса

Tags: android, service

при автозапуске сервис стартует все хорошо context.startService(serviceIntent); когда запускаю приложение при клике на кнопку в активити startService(intent); все хорошо интент передает в сервис. но если нажать кнопку дом на телефоне и закрыть приложение сервис идет на перезапуск (так и должно быть) но на онСтартКоманд застревает и выдает ошибку  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service with null: java.lang.NullPointerException, так как по ходу получает в интент  нал. как решить эту проблему что бы перезапуск было startService(intent); или context.startService(serviceIntent);

Comment: код покажи где проиходит ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Если `onStartCommand` вернет значение `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, то система при перезапуске сервиса пошлет последний `intent`.
Но я не уверен, что в Вашем случае это необходимо. Возможно простой проверки на `null` в `onStartCommand` будет достаточно?

Comment: Да спасибо так и сделал (проверка на нал), служба хоть и не в том состоянии что бы выполнять то что нужно, но это допишу. Самое главное в ошибку больше не вылетает сервис.